Ros foxy cant by located
I want to install ros Foxy on ubuntu 20.04.6 wich is runing in a oracle virtual maschine.
I have followed the instructions but get after copying „ sufo apt install ros-foxy-desktop python3argcomplete“ in the console „ Unable to locate package ros foxy desktop“
